# Generalization of separable ODE for vector equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, vector-analysis

Is there an approach for solving ODEs of the following form?

$$\frac{ d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix} = A(x) \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix} $$

where $A(x)$ is a non-diagonal 2x2 matrix

I tried to do separation of variables, but I am not sure if the operation
$$\frac{d \begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix}}$$
has some meaning

Is it possible to get to an elegant generalized solution , say in the following form?
$$\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix} = C \exp \left( \int A(x)dx\right)$$

Comment: You would need a time-ordered exponential, see quantum physics. The non-commutativity of $A(x)$ for different values of $x$ prevents the simple approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the standard notation for my answer

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}(t)=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{x}(t).$$

If $\boldsymbol{A}(t)=\boldsymbol{A}_0=\boldsymbol{\text{const.}}$ (also called Linear time-invariant systems) then

$\boldsymbol{x}(t)=\exp\left[\boldsymbol{A}_0(t-t_0)\right]\boldsymbol{x}(t_0)$.

If $\boldsymbol{A}(t)$ (also called Linear time-variant systems), hence the coefficient function is only a function of time then you can express the solution by using the [Peano-Baker-Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix#Peano-Baker_series).

$${\mathbf  {\Phi }}(t,t_0)={\mathbf  {I}}+\int _{t_0 }^{t}{\mathbf  {A}}(\sigma _{1})\,d\sigma _{1}$$
$$+\int _{t_0 }^{t}{\mathbf  {A}}(\sigma _{1})\int _{t_0 }^{{\sigma _{1}}}{\mathbf  {A}}(\sigma _{2})\,d\sigma _{2}\,d\sigma _{1}+\int _{t_0 }^{t}{\mathbf  {A}}(\sigma _{1})\int _{t_0 }^{{\sigma _{1}}}{\mathbf  {A}}(\sigma _{2})\int _{t_0 }^{{\sigma _{2}}}{\mathbf  {A}}(\sigma _{3})\,d\sigma _{3}\,d\sigma _{2}\,d\sigma _{1}+...$$

and

$$\boldsymbol{x}(t) = \boldsymbol{\Phi}(t,t_0)\boldsymbol{x}(\tau).$$

Comment: In Ralph's question, $y$ is the dependent variable and $x$ is the independent variable. Thus, $A(x)$ can never lead to a nonlinear system. It is equivalent to a linear time-variant system when $x$ is renamed to $t$.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93: Thank you for pointing that out. I am so used to thinking of $x$ as a state vector and $t$ being the independent variable that I do not even check if the OP did use the same notation.

Comment: @MrYouMath may I ask you why not $x(t) = exp(P(t))x(0)$ where $P(t) = \int_0^t A(s)ds$? If you derive $x(t)$ it seems like it satisfies OP's equation

Comment: First, you need to define what you mean by $\exp(\int_0^{t}A(s)ds)$. Then if you simply carry out the computation of the derivative you will see that you are having trouble with non-commutativity of the matrices.